# stop main from a thread

Tags: c, pthreads, valgrind

I've been tinkering in C on my Raspberry pi, my main() spins up a couple of threads, there's a small webserver that runs in one of those threads,

```
int main(){
        printf("hello world\n");
        thisfn();
        pthread_t tid, led_tid;
        int port = 9193;
        int rc = pthread_create(&tid, NULL, webserver, &port);
        assert (rc == 0);
/snip
```

If the webserver is unable to bind to the desired port, I want the entire program to stop.

```
void *webserver(void *vargp){
    int *port = (int *) vargp;
    printf("our port is %d\n", *port);

    /* First: Socket Creation */
    int sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd < 0){
            /* On error, -1 is returned */
            perror("Server Error!");
            abort();
    } else {
            printf("sockfd is %d\n", sockfd);
    }
    printf("Socket: sockfd: %d\n", sockfd);

    /* Second: Set socket options */
    int optval = 1;
    //int sockopt_int = setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR | SO_REUSEPORT, &optval, sizeof(optval) );
    int sockopt_int = setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR , &optval, sizeof(optval) );
    if ( sockopt_int < 0 ){
            perror("Failed at setsockopt");
            abort();
    } else {
            printf("setsockopt succeeded\n");
    }

    /* Third: Bind to the port */
    /* int bind(int sockfd, const struct sockaddr *addr, socklen_t addrlen); */
    struct sockaddr_in address;
    address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    address.sin_port = htons(*port);

    int bind_int = bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&address, sizeof(address)) ;
    printf("bind_int ; %d\n", bind_int);
    if (bind_int < 0 ) {
            perror("Failed at bind");
            abort(); 
    } else {
            printf("bind succeeded\n");
    }
```

I've been calling abort(), I've also tried exit(1), _exit(1) etc - however, doing so leaks memory (~136 bytes) when I check with valgrind.

```
==13052== 136 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 1 of 1
==13052==    at 0x4849CE0: calloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:711)
==13052==    by 0x401379B: allocate_dtv (dl-tls.c:322)
==13052==    by 0x40141D3: _dl_allocate_tls (dl-tls.c:539)
==13052==    by 0x489D9EF: allocate_stack (allocatestack.c:580)
==13052==    by 0x489D9EF: pthread_create@@GLIBC_2.4 (pthread_create.c:539)
==13052==    by 0x10EBF: main (fixmem.c:38)
==13052== 
==13052== LEAK SUMMARY:
==13052==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==13052==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==13052==      possibly lost: 136 bytes in 1 blocks
==13052==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==13052==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==13052==
```

I've learned of a school of thought, when stuff hits the fan, it is OK to exit out, allowing the OS to cleanup after. I was trying to make it exit/abort with a happier valgrind.  I am not doing any explicit mallocs/callocs in this function to call free() up before abort() - and this bring to my question:

What's the cleanest way to stop main and exit, from a thread?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't do it in the thread. Set up your server socket in mainline, and once everything is good, create a thread with the socket as a parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If the webserver is unable to bind to the desired port, I want the entire program to stop.

If you want the entire program to stop, it is perfectly fine to call `_exit()` - that's what it's for.

Ignore the "leaks" reported by valgrind, they are false positives created by the fact that the cleanup code didn't get a chance to run. Since the OS reclaims all memory (and other resources) belonging to a process that exited, no memory is actually leaked.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect, that if webserver created successfully and thread exit normally there is no memory leak, right? If so, main thread may have some resources to clean up before exit (it seems that pthread_create allocates some memory).

So I may suggest to establish signal handler and do graceful termination of your main thread. Function `abort()` sends signal to process. So you can create signal hander to catch such signal in main thread and to cleanup. [Here](https://airtower.wordpress.com/2010/06/16/catch-sigterm-exit-gracefully/) is good example how this can be done. In example SIGTERM is cathed and atomic variable `done` is set to 1. This variable is periodically checked in main loop and in case of 1 program is terminated. Before such termination you can stop your webserver thread and release memory allocated in pthread_create.

(`abort()` sends SIGABRT, so you'll have to change code from example)

Other ideas:

- Use [`pthread_join`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_join.3.html) from main thread to monitor webserver thread exit code. In webserver thread call [`pthread_exit`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_exit.3.html) to notify main thread of error and to allow graceful termination. Take in account, that pthread_join will block your main thread. But it can be good idea to create several working threads from main and join to them one-by-one.
- Use Mutex/[Conditional](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#ConditionVariables) variable to notify main thread about error. Webserver thread sets such conditional variable to some error code and exit with `return`. Main thread will monitor conditional variable and in case of error do program termination.